# How do I ask the user to input a character that will then be moved across the screen in ASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, output, user-input, dosbox

I currently have the program working to move a number that the user inputs across the screen, but I need it to be a character that the user inputs. How do I convert this program to get a character from the user instead? I have tried using `_GetCh` and `_PutCh` but am having no luck. I am using DOSBox for this ASM program.

```
                include PCMAC.INC
                .model small
                .586
                .stack 100h
                .data
prompt          DB "Please enter a character is be printed: $" 
theChar         DW ?
            
                .code
                extrn GetDec:near
                extrn PutDec:near
                
delay           proc
                push cx ;;save the caller's CX register
                mov ecx,100000
for_2:          nop
                dec ecx
                jnz for_2
                pop cx ;; restore caller's CX
                ret
delay           endp

main            proc
                _Begin
                _PutStr prompt
                call GetDec
                mov theChar, ax
                
                mov cx,80
                
for_1:
                mov ax, theChar
                call PutDec
                call delay
                _PutCh 8,32
                dec cx
                jnz for_1

                _Exit 0
main            endp
                end main
```

I tried to change my `GetDec`/`PutDec` to *Char* and *Ch* but I had no luck. It just wouldn't print anything.

Comment: Overlaps with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74434602/how-do-i-move-from-the-right-side-of-the-prompt-to-the-left-side-in-assembly and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74426368/how-do-i-get-my-character-to-move-back-left-across-the-screen-in-asm

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is in PCMAC.INC, but for DOSBox you should be able to use the DOS functions by number:

To get a character from the user, use function 01h

```
mov  ah, 01h  ; DOS.GetCharacter
int  21h      ; -> AL
```

To put a character on the screen, use function 02h

```
mov  dl, bl
mov  ah, 02h  ; DOS.DisplayCharacter
int  21h
```

You don't need to store and load the character from a variable in memory. You can keep it in the BL register:

```
    _PutStr prompt
    mov  ah, 01h  ; DOS.GetCharacter
    int  21h      ; -> AL
    mov  bl, al   ; `mov theChar, al`

    mov  ah, 02h  ; DOS.DisplayCharacter
    mov  dl, 13   ; Carriage return
    int  21h
    mov  dl, 10   ; Linefeed
    int  21h

    mov  cx, 79
for_1:
    mov  dl, bl   ; `mov  dl, theChar`
    int  21h
    call delay
    mov  dl, 8    ; Backspace
    int  21h
    mov  dl, " "
    int  21h
    dec  cx
    jnz  for_1
```