# How do I move from the right side of the prompt to the left side in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, output, dosbox

I have this program that asks the user for a character, moves that character to the far right side of the screen, and then I need to bring it back to the left. I have it figured out how to move across to the right but I can't figure out how to bring it back to the left. Currently when trying to bring it left it prints the whole line in the character rather than traversing it back to the left side of the screen.

```
                include PCMAC.INC
                .model small
                .586
                .stack 100h
                .data
prompt          DB "Please enter a character is be printed: $" 
userCh          DB ?            
                .code
delay           proc
                push cx ;;save the caller's CX register
                mov ecx,150000
for_2:          nop
                dec ecx
                jnz for_2
                pop cx ;; restore caller's CX
                ret
delay           endp

main            proc
                _Begin
                _PutStr prompt
                _GetCh
                mov userCh, al
                _PutCh 13, 10
                
                mov cx,79
for_1:          _PutCh userCh      ;;print left to right
                call delay
                _PutCh 8,32
                dec cx
                jnz for_1
for_3:                      ;; print right to left
                _PutCh 8
                _PutCh userCh
                call delay
                _PutCh 8
                inc cx
                cmp cx, 79
                jne for_3
                

                _Exit 0
main            endp
                end main
```

Comment: You can display the U+000D (13, Carriage Return) codepoint, then a number of blanks U+0020 to "paint over" what you previously wrote, then another CR and your desired new text. That's how I implemented my own line input function with minimal assumptions about the terminal it connects to.

Comment: You can do it using only Backspace (U+0008) as well if you prefer. You'll have to think along the same lines of painting over what you displayed and then moving the carriage to where you want to newly display however: return carriage by one column, display a blank, then return the carriage twice again. That is, display 8, 32, 8, 8, then your letter.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is close to what is needed!
Working with your macros and using the suggestion that @ecm gave you in her second comment we get:

```
        mov cx, 79
L2R:    _PutCh userCh
        call delay
        _PutCh 8, 32
        dec  cx
        jnz  L2R

        mov  cx, 79
R2L:    _PutCh 8, userCh
        call delay
        _PutCh 8, 32, 8
        dec  cx
        jnz  R2L
```

Now looks are deceiving. For each arg to the *_PuctCh* macro the macro's expansion will insert several lines of code in your program (`mov dl, ?` `mov ah, 02h` `int 21h`).

Next alternative solution uses the BIOS to position the cursor right before outputting the character with one of the BIOS character output functions that does not automatically advance the cursor. Because the cursor is not advanced by the function, you can use all 80 positions instead of the first 79 you had previously.
The first thing the code does is determining on what row the cursor is. The row (in DH) remains constant throughout the loops.

```
        mov  bh, 0        ; CONST DisplayPage
        mov  ah, 03h      ; BIOS.GetCursorConfiguration
        int  10h          ; -> CX DX
        mov  cx, 1        ; CONST ReplicationCount

        mov  dl, 0        ; DH is CONST
L2R:    call tempChar
        inc  dl
        cmp  dl, 80
        jb   L2R

        mov  dl, 79       ; DH is CONST
R2L:    call tempChar
        dec  dl
        jns  R2L

        ...

; ------------------------
; IN (dl) OUT () MOD (ax)
tempChar:                 ; BH (page), CX (count), and DH (row) are CONST
        mov  ah, 02h      ; BIOS.SetCursorPosition
        int  10h
        mov  al, userCh
        mov  ah, 0Ah      ; BIOS.WriteCharacter
        int  10h
        call delay
        mov  ax, 0A20h    ; BIOS.WriteCharacter
        int  10h
        ret
```

The alternative version is both shorter and more adaptable to your ever need.